# Ignore git-svn files from `git log`

Tags: git-svn, logging

Is there a way to ignore git-svn updates?  my usual workflow:

- doing stuff in my `dev` git branch
- checking out my master
- `git svn rebase` on master
- `cherry-pick` from `dev`
- `git svn dcommit`
- checkout dev again
- `git merge master`

the only problem with this is that after i `git merge master`, i do `git log -n ###`, and i get all the `git-svn` updates as well.  Can i limit it just the latest `git` commits?

Comment: Using the dev branch isn't getting you much since you're not merging or squashing commits. Either work on the trunk, work on dev with merges, or continually re-branch dev from master.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't merge master back into the dev-branch without getting the git-svn commits along for the ride.

The thing is that when you do a git svn dcommit, you actually **rewrite** the commits that you've cherry-picked from the dev branch. The git-svn commits are now part of your history, and it would be folly to try to get rid of them some how. If I'm guessing correctly, your dev branch is full of merge commits where your git-svn commits are re-joined with your dev-commits because they have diverged. This is messy.

That being said, I'm also unsure if your workflow is optimal. Maybe you should try this:

1. work work work in the `dev` branch
2. `git svn rebase` on master for the lastest svn changes
3. Now rebase these latest changes in under your work: `git rebase master` in `dev`
4. Now fast-forward your changes back to master: `git merge dev` on `master`
5. `git svn dcommit` on master
6. Now remove the dev branch. Little sense in keeping it since the commits have now been rewritten by dcommit. `git branch -d dev`
7. `git checkout -b dev` for the next feature/fix.

Comment: thanks thomas. I'll give this workflow a go and see how it is.